# global.getElementById('...') is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

In my project, I have designed a JavaScript page to render HTML data but I'm getting the above error. My code is:

```
global.getElementById('divPartnerGrid').innerHTML = "<table width='100%'><tr><td align='middle' style='vertical-align:middle; position:centre;'><img src='../Content/images/ajax-loader(2).gif'/></td></tr><tr><td align='middle' style='vertical-align:middle; position:centre;'>"+loadingLabel+"...</td></tr></table>"
```

While running the project,it will break at this line. Can anyone please let me know, what caused this error to come?

Comment: Does an element with ID `divPartnerGrid` exist? If `global` is not `document` and `#divPartnerGrid` does not exist then this code won't work and you have to fix it accordingly. From the error message it seems that the element `#divPartnerGrid` does not exist... so, either create such an element or use the correct ID.

Comment: `position: centre` in your style is invalid

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling..actually in xslt code,i didn't use divPartnerGrid..due to that the error is coming in js page..just i defined the "div" and now its working

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what `global` is either but the `getElementById` method is defined on the `document` so you probably simply want

```
document.getElementById('divPartnerGrid').innerHTML = "...";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `global` with `document`, even if global is a variable you created that points to `window` (or `this` in the global scope), you still need a document in which you want to search for elements.

Also, make sure the page is loaded before this script runs: you can't get an element if it's not loaded yet

Answer (score 0):

You have probably copied the global thing from an example that has encapsulated the global variable while you haven't done the same.

This is done in the following example where the document (which is probably what you want to use as others have pointed out) where document is sent in to the self envoking function so that global inside that scope would actually refer to document.

```
;(function(global) {

    global.getElementById(/* */);

})(document);
```

This is typical for libraries that could be used on the server where the global value may be different from the one in a browser.